# Why does --module override Typescript compiler's --out flag?

Tags: node.js, typescript

If I run `$ tsc --out foo.js MyFile.ts` I get the file `foo.js`.  However if I specify the `--module commonjs` option, the `--out` parameter is overriden and I get **MyFile.js** ie: `$ tsc --out foo.js --module commonjs MyFile.ts`

Given I use the `export` assignment in my TS code to have my classes available to my NodeJS JS code, I obviously need the `--module` flag.  However I think it's a bug that the `--out` flag value is ignored/overridded.

The reason is that I want to suffix the generated JS code with .gen.js so that I can write an SCM rule to ignore the generated code.

```
$ node --version && tsc --version
v0.10.22
Version 0.9.7.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--out` is ignored for files that are multiple modules because it's not really clear what that even means (what if you had specified `tsc --out foo.js Module1.ts Module2.ts`, where `Module1` had `require`'d `Module2`?).

The theory here is that you would use your external build tool (grunt, jake, make, frakes, etc) to rename your file afterwards if you wanted it to be named something different. It's very rarely intended to compile an external module file to some other filename, since it would compile but not run.

[There's a CodePlex issue](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/759) you can vote on to show your support for implementing this post-1.0.

Comment: You raise a good point @ryan-cavanaugh about the modules, however I'm using WebStorm's File Watchers to convert my TS into JS, which directly invokes tsc.  I'll probably have to rejig it to delegate via Grunt instead.